# Is this an example of a basic/simple higher-order function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

While reading [Eloquent Javascript (Chapter 6)](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html) I am trying to grasp fundamental concepts. There is discussion about Higher-Order functions in Javascript. Is the function processNumbers() in the following code a Higher-Order function?

```
function addNumbers(number1, number2) {
  return (number1 + number2);   
}

function processNumbers(action, number1, number2) {
  return action(number1, number2);
}

document.write(processNumbers(addNumbers, 2, 10));​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [Wikipedia article on Higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> In mathematics and computer science, a higher-order function (also functional form, functional or functor) is a function that does at least one of the following:
>
> - take one or more functions as an input
> - output a function

So yes, `processNumbers` is a higher-level function as it takes in a function as input via the `action` parameter.